# C++11 efficient vector member initialization?

Tags: c++11, initialization, stdvector

What is the best way to initialize a vector member object in C++11?  Will the compiler optimize away the copy in `foo` or will `bar` be more efficient?

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// C++11 style
struct foo
{
        vector<int> vec = vector<int>(256);
};

// traditional
struct bar
{
        bar() : vec(256) {}
        vector<int> vec;
};
```

Comment: usually it's best to start a vector as empty since push_back is actually very efficient

Comment: @aaronman, good point.  And if you're determined to give some hint to the system about the expected size, there's alway [`vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve)

Comment: Default-initialized dynamic arrays are weird in C++. C++ separates memory allocation from object creation, so you should maybe allocate the memory up front (with `reserve`), but only create the objects when you actually have them. (For example, default-initialization of a vector causes all the elements to be accessed, which may be unnecessary and wasteful.)

Comment: @KerrekSB that's why they were supposed to add `std::dynarray` but it was taken out

Comment: @aaronman: Mm, I think even that would have initialized the elements. I'm not sure, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++11 there probably isn't much difference between them. For example foo does not copy a large vector. The right hand side of the `=` is an rvalue and will be `move`d to the left hand side. The only difference is the creation (and quick removal) of the 0-element vector within `foo`. But that'll take up no time.

**But**, both C++11 and C++03 allow optimizations ('elision') to skip the assignment in foo. Therefore they can both be very efficient in both standards.